# Full text search for exact match_phrase (with leading and trailing whitespace) in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm new to Elasticsearch and here is my task at hand.

Given my index:

```
{
   "my_index": {
      "mappings": {
         "_default_": {
            "_all": {
               "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {}
         },
         "title": {
            "_all": {
               "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
               "foo_id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "english"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings": {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

And sample records:

```
{"foo_id": 777, "title": "Equality"}
{"foo_id": 777, "title": "First Among Equals"}
{"foo_id": 777, "title": "AN EQUAL MUSIC"}
```

I would like to search for records that must:

- have foo_id == 777
- contain case-insensitive word "equal"

Meaning, I must find only third record, containing exact phrase "equal". Titles containing words "equality" and "equals" must not be returned. I'd like to avoid resorting to regexp.

I tried a searching like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term": {"account_id": 777}},
        {"match_phrase": {"title": "equal"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but it returns all three results.

Additional question: how can I get results in the most efficient way, given that I don't care about relevancy of the results? Should I use `search_type='scan'` with scroll or maybe filtering? A snippet would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it. If you take out the english analyzer, the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will be used instead, which seems to give you what you want.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index" -d'
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 2, 
         "number_of_replicas": 1
      },
      "mappings": {
         "_default_": {
            "_all": {
               "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {}
         },
         "title": {
            "_all": {
               "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
               "foo_id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "title": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
}'
```

Then add the docs:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/title/1" -d'
{"foo_id": 777, "title": "Equality"}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/title/2" -d'
{"foo_id": 777, "title": "First Among Equals"}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/title/3" -d'
{"foo_id": 777, "title": "AN EQUAL MUSIC"}'
```

Then you can use a [constant score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html#query-dsl-constant-score-query) query to avoid extra computation (if you don't care about the ranking of results), combined with a [must bool filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) to get the results you want:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
       "filter": {
           "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {"term": {
                     "foo_id": 777
                  }},
                  {"term": {
                     "title": "equal"
                  }}
               ]
           }
       }
    }
  }
}'
```

yielding:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "title",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "foo_id": 777,
               "title": "AN EQUAL MUSIC"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/179d737edf1de964090746a2fdae5ad52c935b31

**EDIT**: If you want to be able to use the english analyzer as well as the standard analyzer (or some other analyzer, or none, as is often the case for faceting or sorting) you can use a [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) (deprecated name) as follows:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 2,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
         "_all": {
            "enabled": false
         },
         "properties": {}
      },
      "title": {
         "_all": {
            "enabled": false
         },
         "properties": {
            "foo_id": {
               "type": "long"
            },
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "english",
               "fields": {
                  "unstemmed": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "standard"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Now, if you search with `{ "term": { "title": "equal" } }` you will get all three docs, but if you use `{ "term": { "title.unstemmed": "equal" } }` you will get what you want:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "foo_id": 777
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "title.unstemmed": "equal"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "title",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "foo_id": 777,
               "title": "AN EQUAL MUSIC"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/40a145e94fd8e47b875525c7e095024f025dd1ab

Comment: As commented on another answer: is there any way to do what I want and keep english analyzer?

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see the first answer. Yes, it's possible to do what you're asking by using "sub-fields" (not sure the actual name). Hold on a minute and I'll see if I can set something up for you.

Comment: multi_fields: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html#_multi_fields

Comment: Here is the code: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/06ba196d385764e6968fb09c8647643e45f60835. I'll edit my answer to explain it.

Comment: Thanks this is the correct answer. Although we should use the new syntax for multi fields: `"title": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "english", "fields": {"raw": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "standard"}}}`. Consider editing your answer for the coming generations of searchers :)

Comment: Good point. Will do. Also it makes sense to use "unstemmed" (or something) instead of "raw". :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I intend to do. `Explicit is better than implicit.` Elasticsearch DSL is complex enough. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

currently you're using the [english analyser](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer):

```
           "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
```

If you don't want to do stemming etc. (to avoid picking up "equals", "equality") then switch to a simpler analyser.  For example use the [Standard](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) or [Simple](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) analyser instead - or even create your own.

```
           "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "standard"
```

once set up, use a `match` or `query_string` query to find the relevant document.

---

If you want to retain the Stem analyser but also support an alternative form of analysis then you should use [multi-fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html)

For example:

```
"title": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "english",
    "fields": {
       "std": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "standard" }
     }
}
```

When you want to do a search using the `standard` analyser, use the field `title.std`

Comment: I plan to have more queries, such that will utilize stemming. Should I create a separate index with different analyzer? Maybe I can have two analyzers process a single field and select which analyzer to use per search?

Comment: I you want to apply more than one analyser to a field you should use [multi-fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html). I'll update the answer.